# How can I change multiple images each day to different ones from the same folder using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, random

Im gunna try this again in more detail so I have a website with multiple images on the home page which I change manually each week from my images folder which has over 500 images, is there a way I can do this using javascript so each day it changes so a different image, kind of like storing all the image links in a javascript file, does this make sense?

here is the code to display each section take a look at the website page so you can understand more what I mean wealthybones dot com

```html
<h3 class="no-title">Recently Added</h3>
        <div class="no">
            <img src="images/move.png" alt="">
            <a href="files/jamaledwards"><img src="images/deadhome/jamaledwards.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/margaretjohn"><img src="images/deadhome/margaretjohn.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/michaelgambon"><img src="images/deadhome/michaelgambon.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/halroach"><img src="images/deadhome/halroach.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/genekelly"><img src="images/deadhome/genekelly.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/petercushing"><img src="images/deadhome/petercushing.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/jimhenson"><img src="images/deadhome/jimhenson.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/hennyyoungman"><img src="images/deadhome/hennyyoungman.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/donaldpleasence"><img src="images/deadhome/donaldpleasence.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="files/brookemccarter"><img src="images/deadhome/brookemccarter.png" alt=""></a>
            <a href="#search22"><img src="images/search.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This would usually been done server side, do you have control on the server? It would be easier because the server can list all images in the folder and pick randomly from the list. It's more efficient than the server sending a list of all images and the client picking from it

Answer (score 0):

you can give IDs to all the images and use this
document.getElementById("image-id").src= "../template/save.png";

also add index in the file name of image
and create a function and this function should have a for loop which can assign random images to the img.scr like this : document.getElementById("image-id").src= "../template/save[index].png";

Comment: can't you give me an example to my current code layout and where to this example?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that store all the images

```js
const images = ["name", "nameA", "nameB", "..."]
```

Then create a function to handle how many images you want to show on the website and provide two parameters, first is the array itself and the number of images you want to show. Here we can use javascript slice method to select random images

```js
const selectImages = (images, gap) => {
    const firstImg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (images.length - gap) + 1)
    const lastImg = firstImg - gap

    return images.slice(firstImg, lastImg)
}
```

Now use the `setInterval()` method to execute the selectImages function and update the html each day using DOM Manipulation

```js
setInterval(() => {
    const selectedImages = selectImages(images, 10)
    
    // looping the selected images and do DOM Manipulation
}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

I believe there is a more convenient way to accomplish this task.

Comment: hello sorry I can't make any sense of that